# Why there is no put on concurrent hashmap with operation outcome? And what's the use case of putIfAbsent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have delved into concurrency and really struggling to understand some designs used in concurrent data structures i.e. concurrent hash map.

There are some statements I made and questions in bold, please help me to confirm and answer them.

`putIfAbsent` cannot tell to executing thread whether it actually replaced the key with a new value or it took the existing old because in both cases it will return the old value. So what's the point of 'putIfAbsent' as in majority use cases we actually report to end client/user/about operation outcome, I understand that this might be generalisation but still? Most of us would probably be delighted with `Optional<Entry<K,V>> putIfAbsentAndReturnValueIfPut(K,V)` , something along those lines :-) ?

What do I gain from `putIfAbsent` atomicity? **I still need to use synchronised access if I want to report on the outcome of operation for the end user.**

Imagine following structure:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Outcome someMethod(String key, Integer value) {
   Integer returnedValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, value);// ??? so how do I know if I updated the value?
   map.get(key).equals(value); // even if I compare, I am not in  synchronized context

}
```

So if my key is UUID, in the very long run it might generate duplicate key for new map entry, how do I ensure that if second thread calls "put" after first with the same key:

- A. Operation happens, a thread attempts to put.
- B. Operation outcome
  is known, so second thread can try to regenerate a new UUID and try
  put again or notify the caller that the operation has failed?

Update: thanks everyone, this is one of those days..

Comment: It sounds like you might not have gotten the whole "IfAbsent" part of the method name. `putIfAbsent` will never update an old value. If it returns a non-null value, you know that an old value existed and was left unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always find out, whether the value has been added or was already present by inspecting the return value of `putIfAbsent`:

```
final ConcurrentMap<String,Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
final Object old = map.putIfAbsent("hello", "world");

if (old != null) {

    // The value was already present and has not been modified
    // by the call.

} else {

    // There was no prior entry, and "world" has been assigned
    // as value for key "hello"
}
```

Note, that this is still ambiguous, if the map implementation accepts `null` as value for an entry. (Probably) for this reason, `ConcurrentHashMap` does not accept `null` for keys and values:

> Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.

(as is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html))

Comment: This kind of thing is why `ConcurrentHashMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` don't allow `null` keys or values.

Comment: Yep. I was looking for a reference in the documentation.

Comment: this would only work if that is first time put? What happens if a thread tried to put value with the same key as previous thread? In old you would get old value from put operation done by previous thread.

Comment: @Aubergine: Then you enter the `old != null` case, and you know that a previous entry existed and was not replaced.

Comment: @Aubergine - The return value is `null` if (and only if) there was no prior value. If there actually was (even if it is the same as the one supplied as value argument in `putIfAbsent`) the return value is non-`null`, and you *know*, that nothing has been changed by the call.

Comment: @Dirk 
I think I got lost, when I read javadoc:
Returns:
the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key

so if thread 1 putIfAbsent ("a", 1) and thread 2 putIfAbsent ("a", 2) , the return of second call will be 1 right? How does this not null check helps me in this situation i don't understand :-( I still don't know whether resulting value is from previous thread call or this thread call.

Comment: You cannot modify an *existing* entry with `putIfAbsent`. The `IfAbsent` in the method name should give a strong clue here... ;-) In your scenario, only *one* of the threads can ever succeed with its `putIfAbsent` calls. After it did so, the value is no longer *absent*.

Answer (score 0):

*"`putIfAbsent` cannot tell to executing thread whether it actually replaced the key with a new value or it took the existing old because in both cases it will return the old value."*

Did you actually *read* the javadoc of [`putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-)? Seems you read the javadoc of [`put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) and *assumed* that `putIfAbsent()` behaves the same. It doesn't:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns `null`, else returns the current value.

Since [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) does *not* allow `null` to be used as a key or value, you'll know for sure if the method added the value. `null` means value was added, non-`null` means value was not added and return value is the value already in the map.

**Definitive detection of outcome!!**